# Amazon S3 direct uploads via forge.request.ajax

Tags: amazon-s3, trigger.io

I'm trying to upload camera media from Trigger's File and Camera module to S3 using S3's direct upload support (http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434). I've gotten this working with the native web just fine, but I'm getting S3's "MaxPostPreDataLengthExceeded" exception when I duplicate the same request in Trigger.

I've looked at the raw requests and it looks like one subtle difference is causing the failure in trigger.

Here's the raw POST data coming from Webkit:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCl5fCuacIKQjcEfA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

uploads/2013-08-29/upload.jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryCl5fCuacIKQjcEfA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

...

------WebKitFormBoundaryCl5fCuacIKQjcEfA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundaryCl5fCuacIKQjcEfA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

????JFIF??XExifMM?i&??...
```

And here it is from `forge.request.ajax({data: ..., files: [(file object)]})`:

```
--2268A38A1BB344B5BBEE83586818388A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

uploads/2013-08-30/upload.jpeg
--2268A38A1BB344B5BBEE83586818388A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

...

--2268A38A1BB344B5BBEE83586818388A
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
--2268A38A1BB344B5BBEE83586818388A
Content-Disposition: file; name="file"; filename="file.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

????JFIF??XExifMM?i&??...
```

The (only) difference is that in webkit using the FormData field, files have the `form-data` content disposition. In trigger, files have the `file` content disposition. Which is causing S3 to register the file binary contents as part of the form; hence the `MaxPostPreDataLengthExceeded` exception and 400 Bad Request response.

Is there a reason for this difference? I don't see in the docs any way to customize the Content-Disposition for these files. Is there such a way? Do I need to build this functionality myself? I don't see S3 changing, so are there any options for getting this to work within Trigger's functionality?

Comment: Gabe, Any chance you should share your code?  I am still having this same issue and get get passed it.  I am having the identical problem

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this was just a bug in the Trigger upload code, I've just published an updated version of the request module (version 2.2) which fixes this.

Thanks for such a detailed description of your problem.

Comment: This still isn't working for me using request module version 2.4.  Could someone share some working code possibly? @gabe-s?